# DB2 sql function with return table (udtf) and cursor won't compile (Error: Clauses are mutually exclusive)

Tags: sql, function, db2

I've found so much help on this site for my problems, but after hours of searching various sites I'm completly stuck this time (or just using the wrong terms to search).

I have the following problem on a db2 (9.7) function which should return a table(udtf):

I want to create a function which calculates some score with different dependencies. Since it has to do that on multiple rows because of cross dependency I wanted it to return the results as a table. As an intermediate step I use another (temporary) table to save the results (for later use).

I have created the following table to save some scores

`CREATE TABLE TEMP_SCORE (
    ID INTEGER NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
    var1 INTEGER NOT NULL,
    var2 INTEGER NOT NULL,
    score INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    max_score NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 )`

Now I'm trying to use use the following function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION doSomething(IDvalue INTEGER) 
RETURNS TABLE ( ID      INTEGER,
            var1 INTEGER,
            var2 INTEGER,
            score INTEGER,
            max_score INTEGER)
LANGUAGE SQL
SPECIFIC doSomething
MODIFIES SQL DATA
BEGIN 
    DECLARE reached_score INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE calculated_max_score INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE currentID INTEGER DEFAULT NULL;

DECLARE someCursor WITH HOLD FOR
SELECT --- someDATA ---
FROM --- a lot of JOINS, SELECTS and INNER JOINS (statement collect the correct data) ---

OPEN someCursor;
FETCH someCursor INTO currentID, reached_score, calculated_max_score;

WHILE SQLSTATE != '02000' DO
    ... some SQL Code (set, select, some more calculation on variables of the cursor) ...

    INSERT INTO TEMP_SCORE(
          var1, var2, score, max_score
          ) values (
          IDvalue, currentID, reached_score, calculated_max_score
          );

    FETCH someCursor INTO currentID, reached_score, other_max_score;
END WHILE;

RETURN (SELECT ID, var1, var2, score, max_score
       FROM TEMP_SCORE 
       WHERE var1 = IDvalue
       ORDER BY var1 DESC, var2 ASC);
END
```

Now I'm trying so save/compile this function but it says "Clauses are mutually exclusive " (I hope this is the correct translation) with SQLSTATE 42613, SQLCODE -628 (SQL0628N).

I hope anyone could help me out since I just can't see the mistake I made or at least point me in the right direction. 
Many thanks in advance.

Comment: You seem to be RBARing things anyways (by reading then inserting each line).  Is it not possible to do everything in one statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`RETURNS TABLE` conflicts with `MODIFIES SQL DATA` -- this is only allowed in [*inlined* SQL functions](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0004240.html?cp=SSEPGG_10.5.0%2F2-12-7-54&lang=en), which in turn have their own restrictions, for example, they don't allow cursors. I guess you'll need to rethink the approach to whatever you're trying to do. One option might be to rewrite your function as a procedure returning a result set.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.
I wanted to use this in Java/myBatis to create some score beans from the result table.
But since the dependencies in and among the score calculations have become more complex I put the function into a stored procedure and use my tempTable as storage for future calculations on the scores.
Thanks again!

Comment: `RETURNS TABLE conflicts with MODIFIES SQL DATA` -- Is that documented for DB2 9.7? [CREATE FUNCTION (SQL scalar, table, or row)](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0003493.html?pos=2) shows them together in Example 4, and I haven't seen that restriction.

Comment: @user2338816 -- see note 5 in the link you posted.

Comment: @mustaccio Ah. Very good matching of details back to the original code, though it's still not clear how the noted clauses would be the ones referenced by the given error.